# How can write a C function in a C# code

Tags: .net, c, com

I want to add a C file into my .NET application.

How can I built this?
How can i write unmanaged code in C#.
Can someone explain with few lines code.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to use your c language function try to make a dll for this, and use dll with com components in your .net application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You either have to build the C file into it's own DLL and then [use P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx) in your C# code to call them or...

You could also try to port the C code to C# which would give you a completely managed codebase.

Comment: I would recommend the second option.

Comment: @Alexander - If the C code-base is small, then I would agree. However, I've seen some pretty monolithic C files that would be difficult to port to C#.